# How to get the details of an object

Tags: php, json

Using the code below:

```
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'w') or die("Can't open file.");
// output the value as a variable by setting the 2nd parameter to true
$results = print_r($_REQUEST['lat'], true);
fwrite($fh, $results);
fclose($fh);
```

I am trying to output the incoming object and it's references. The inbound object is

```
$_REQUEST['lat'];
```

But when I finally get the print out, all I am getting is:

```
[object Object]
```

I've tried multiple ways to get the data of the object, but nothing is working. What am I missing here?

When I run just the `$_REQUEST` with the `print_r` function I get this:

```
Array
(
    [lat] => [object Object]
    [long] => [object Object]
)
```

Comment: Try using var_dump() instead of print_r() and show the output here.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['lat']->something` would help ?

Comment: @Zl3n that's what I am trying to figure out - what the $_REQUEST['lat']->something is so I can work with it further

Comment: Ran your code. Ran fine. What I put in lat was in the log file.

Answer (score 2):

The string `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects in `javascript`. It looks like you are trying to send a request from javascript (ajax?) to your php code and instead of sending the data you are sending the object.

If you have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php", 
    data: {'lat' : $('#input_element') }
    success: function(result){
        ...
    }
});
```

You should actually do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php", 
    data: {'lat' : $('#input_element').val() }
    success: function(result){
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: It's actually coming from appery.io so I'm just trying to capture the data that's coming to the script

Comment: I guess you should change the code you run in appery.io to make sure it sends you the correct data.

Comment: Can't it's appery's service that pushes it that way

Comment: I'm not familiar with their service, but if it's something that you send them from your app and they send it back to you - then you should change your app. If it's something that they send you regardless - you might wanna ask them to check their code.